# Android javascript injection, how would I call this function $(document).ready(function(){...})

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview, code-injection

I am working on some javascript injection into m android webview. I am just not completely sure of the syntax it is looking for

I want to call this function in my html page:
`$(document).ready(function({...})`

I have a webview and javascript interface setup in my app. I also have javascript enabled

```
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mydocument.html");
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new myJavaScriptInterface(), "jsintector");
    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:ready()");
```

the `javascript:ready()` is supposed to be the part in the android that calls the correct function in the html page. What is the proper syntax to access this function? `$(document).ready(function({...})`

(edit: the javascript is already in the html, I just want to force it to run from the android side)

Comment: the function is already there in the html data? or you want to inject it?

Comment: the function is already in the html data, I want to force it to execute on the occassions that android does not load it properly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to search before...

Anyway, the simplest way to do this is to do the following:

1. `load the url into a string`
2. `inject the javascript into the string`
3. use [loaddata](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to load the html into the webview

Comment: Yeah, you have to force android to load javascript sometimes even after the page has loaded, if you search you'll see this is a common problem here - frequently unanswered.  The javascript is already in the html file